# Lilypond: Additional vertical space between stanzas

Tags: lilypond

How can I add additional vertical space between stanzas in order to visually group stanzas? Here is a MWE:

```
\version "2.22.2"

\score {
  <<  
    \new Voice = msx { c' d' e' f' }
    \new Lyrics \lyricsto msx { 
      <<
        \new Lyrics { \set stanza = "1" one two three four }
        \new Lyrics { \set stanza = "2" two two three four }
        \new Lyrics { \set stanza = "3" one two three three }
        \new Lyrics { \set stanza = "4" one two three two }
      >>  
      }
  >>
}
```

Here is the actual result:

[image: Result of the compilation]

And here is what I want it to look like:

[image: Space added between stanzas 2 and 3]

Simply adding `\markup \vspace #1` in the lyrics doesn't seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way by overriding the `VerticalAxisGroup.nonstaff-nonstaff-spacing`:

```
\version "2.22.2"

\score {
  <<  
    \new Voice = msx { c' d' e' f' }
    \new Lyrics \lyricsto msx { 
      <<
        \new Lyrics { \set stanza = "1" one two three four }
        \new Lyrics \with { \override VerticalAxisGroup.nonstaff-nonstaff-spacing = #'((basic-distance . 5)) } { \set stanza = "2" two two three four }
        \new Lyrics { \set stanza = "3" one two three three }
        \new Lyrics { \set stanza = "4" one two three two }
      >>  
      }
  >>
}
```